# Water damage to the passport with a valid visa

Tags: visas, spain, damaged-passports

I have left my passport in my jacket. Without knowing that it got washed. Now my passport is damaged by water. It had a Spanish visa, where I'm supposed to travel in the next weeks. I'm going to apply for a new passport. But what do I have to do with the visa? The paper in the passport that has the visa got bent due to the damage. What will be the solution for this case?

Comment: Are every details of the visa clear and readable?

Comment: Hello thanks for the response. All the information and letter are clear. Only the page got twisted and bended